# How to find accurate reference voltage and how to set them to ADCON register of PIC10LF322?

Tags: adc, pic, pwm, low-power, voltage-reference

I am a beginner who is interested to learn more about PIC controllers and currently I am working on a small project to turn ON an LED indicator based on the input voltage. I am using [PIC10LF322](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC10%28L%29F320-322-Data-Sheet-40001585E.pdf) and I would like my circuit to operate with extreme low power. But I am having trouble with Reference voltage. How to determine Accurate value of Vref (reference voltage) that does not fluctuate with system conditions such as input voltage or ambient temperature and how to set them ADC?

Any information would be really helpful.

I am using Xc8 compiler and MPLAB X IDE v6.00

Comment: Regarding the voltage fluctuations you mentioned: You need a source of accurate Voltage for Vreference, or you need to know how to program your MCU so that it will have more accurate Vref and more accurate readings? The input voltage to your MCU must be noise-free for accurate voltage reference. Also some MCUs have separate Vref pins, where you put your Vref there, which also has to be noise-free for accurate measurements. Your Analog input trace/wire which you want to measure must also be noise-free. 
Could you be more specific, which of the above you need help for?

Comment: PIC10LF322 always uses its VDD to construct an ADC result. But it does provide an internal voltage reference voltage source which can be read-in just like an **analog input**. You can set this voltage reference to say, 1.024V, then input a reading. You'd use that reading to calibrate the internal ADC module. For example, with VDD=+5.000V, reading \$V_{ref}\$ should give a 0x34 ADC result. You may have to read some documentation (data sheet, Xc8 docs).

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios, Thank you for helping me understand the concept better. I need help with programming the MCU for accurate Vref and accurate readings. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  PIC10LF322's [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC10%28L%29F320-322-Data-Sheet-40001585E.pdf), at page 86 it mentions that if you use ADC during sleep, it can reduce the noise in your readings.
It is common in MCUs that the ADC can operate during sleep so that the reading is more accurate.

[image: ADC OPERATION DURING SLEEP]

You might find more information regarding using ADC in sleep mode in its other datasheets [here](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC10F322#document-table).

Again, filtering the power of the MCU using capacitors or ferrites or inductors or a combination of the above, depending on the frequency of the noise, is recommended for lower noise measurements.